# indexOf returning -1 and 7 for the same input

Tags: javascript

`("iwsgroupware").indexOf("http://iwsgroupware");` is returning

> -1

whereas `("http://iwsgroupware").indexOf("iwsgroupware");` is returning

> 7

Why is this so?

Comment: Those are not the same. `.indexOf()` is used like `haystack.indexOf('needle')`, so while blue would be found within blueberry, blueberry wouldn't be found within blue.

Comment: Please first learn what indexOf() operation actually does.

Comment: `(search_this_string).indexOf(for_this_string)` <- this is how it works, and the first returns `-1` for obvious reasons, the second string does not occur in the first string.

Comment: For the same reason that `3 / 1 = 3` whereas `1 / 3 = 0`;  When you change the values, the result also changes.

Comment: thanks for all your reply. @David I asked this question because for some reason 3*1 and 1*3 is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

First of all you have to know about indexOf().

**Answer is:**

```
returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.
```

In `("iwsgroupware").indexOf("http://iwsgroupware");`

`iwsgroupware` does't contains the string `http://iwsgroupware`.

So it returns `-1`

Where as `("http://iwsgroupware").indexOf("iwsgroupware");`

`http://iwsgroupware` contains the string `iwsgroupware`.

So here indexOf() returns value `7`

Answer (score 2):

The two inputs are not the same.

```
("iwsgroupware").indexOf("http://iwsgroupware");
```

Since `"iwsgroupware"` doesn't contain the String `"http://iwsgroupware"`, -1 is returned. On the other hand,

```
("http://iwsgroupware").indexOf("iwsgroupware");
```

`"http://iwsgroupware"` does contain the String `"iwsgroupware"`, so its index (7) is returned.